# Openwhisk on-premise install error

Tags: openwhisk

I tried to install an openwhisk VM on a windows 10 machine.
Cloned the git repo, cd'd to openwhisk/tools/vagrant and run ./hello.

Many, many minutes later, I get the following error.

> ```
> ==> default: :index
> ==> default: :goPrepare
> ==> default:  FAILED
> ==> default: FAILURE:
> ==> default: Build failed with an exception.
> ==> default:
> ==> default: * What went wrong:
> ==> default: Execution failed for task ':goPrepare'.
> ==> default: > Create symbolic link at /home/vagrant/openwhisk/bin/openwhisk-cli/.gogradle/project_gopath/src/github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk-cli
> ```
>
> failed

Though I can find the index task in build.gradle, I can not find the goPrepare task under openwhisk-cli or the parent directories.

I presume this command was run on the newly created VM as I get

```
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

But running vagrant ssh does log me on to the VM.

Looking at the vagrantfile, there is

```
  # Clone and Build CLI
    echo "`date`: build-cli-start" >> /tmp/vagrant-times.txt
    cd ${OPENWHISK_HOME}/bin
    rm -rf openwhisk-cli
    su vagrant -c 'git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk-cli.git openwhisk-cli'
    cd openwhisk-cli
    su vagrant -c './gradlew releaseBinaries'
    echo "`date`: build-cli-end" >> /tmp/vagrant-times.txt
```

The log in /tmp shows build-cli-start but not build-cli-end.

The releaseBinaries task is in build.gradle but no links there.

Has anyone else come across this error? Does anyone know where the goPrepare task is?

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Raised defect at https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk/issues/3649.

Fixed in https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk/pull/3651.

Updated git, run hello again and it works. Congrats to the openwhisk team for responding so quickly.